# batch file to check if the specific word "test" exist in the files, IF exist copy the whole folder to another location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

How can I check if the word "test" exist in any files inside a folder(that contain tons of folders and files) .. and if exist, copy the whole folder to another location.

Please help thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /c:"test" *.txt > NUL
if not errorlevel 1 xcopy *.* anotherlocation
```

If you want to check all files beneath current folder at any level, add /S switch in findstr command. Do the same in xcopy command to copy the whole folder structure.

Comment: No. Although it should work in any file, how you expect to find the "test" or any string in a file that not contain text? It depends ultimately on the operation of findstr command, that works on any file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
findstr /c:"Finished schedule" E:\Init.log > NUL 
if "!errorlevel!"=="0" 
( echo "OK" )
else ( echo "NOK" )
```